# jQuery How to transmit data to another page (button, checkbox)

Tags: jquery

I have a data table with a button column and a checkbox column (and other columns filled with DB).

I have a script which fetches an ID of my checkbox

My table (HTML :

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning boutonsolo" >Facturer</a>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="ckbox ckbox-success">
     <input type="checkbox" class="select-facture" name="id_commande[]" value ="<?= $commande->getId() ?>"/>
     <label for="checkboxSuccess"></label>
  </div>
</td>
```

But now when I click on the button in my column I want to get an ID and I which further redirects the user to other page persisting that ID.

The only script I have made for this is :

```
$('.boutonsolo').click(function() {
  var test = $('.select-facture').val();
  alert(test);
});
```

Comment: Different pages cannot share data unless it is stored somewhere, like on a server in a database, the url, or in the browser (localStorage, IndexedDB, etc.) You will need to store the information somewhere and then retrieve it when the new page loads.

Comment: Okay thanks for the anwser i will try to store this in my DB :)

Comment: You need to persist the id using php, js won't persist for you

Comment: Thanks for the anwser i will check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys I have found a solution, i can't show you because of my work but I have used window.location and some functions in my code.
Thank you all for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage/sessionStorage API Provided by the HTML5 . Storing the value to the DB and then fetching it again requires you to do Http Request, but if you store it in localStorage/sessionStorage you can fetch it just like fetching any value from variable. One more method you can use is pass it through link, which will show the user your id on the address bar. So the best way is localStorage.

```
if( localStorage ){
    localStorage.id = your_id;
}
```

Comment: Tank you for anwsering, i will search about this technic too :)

Comment: @CryZemo if the technic is relevant, don't forget to upvote :)